# Expected Expression and adding extra brackets

Tags: ios, objective-c

Okay I've been working on this for days on end and i can't seem to figure out why i keep getting the expected expresion and why Xcode wants me to add extra brackets around my code. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == self.objects.count)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    static NSString *CellIdentifier    = @"SectionHeaderCell";
    UITableViewCell *sectionHeaderView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UILabel *userName           = (UILabel *)[sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:1];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM d, h:mm a"];

    UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel *)[sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:2];

    PFObject *post = [self.objects objectAtIndex:section];
    PFUser *user   = [post objectForKey:@"username"];
    userName.text  = user.username;

    //follow button
    //problem is here
    LikeButton *LikeButton  = (LikeButton *)[sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:3];
    //^^^^
    LikeButton.delegate     = self;
    LikeButton.sectionIndex = section;



    if (!self.likeArray || [user.objectId isEqualToString:[PFUser currentUser].objectId])
    {
        LikeButton.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        LikeButton.hidden = NO;
        NSInteger indexOfMatchedObject = [self.likeArray indexOfObject:user.objectId];
        if (indexOfMatchedObject == NSNotFound)
        {
            LikeButton.selected = NO;
        }
        else
        {
            LikeButton.selected = YES;
        }
    }
    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

Comment: On what line exactly is this error showing up? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: And please fix your indenting so a human can read it properly.

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to have a instance variable the exact name as the class? `LikeButton *LikeButton`

Comment: What line is identified as having the error?????

Comment: @HotLicks It's pointed out in the code.

Comment: @rmaddy - Not very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing a lot of issues in your code.

```
LikeButton *LikeButton = (LikeButton *)[sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:3];
```

You declared your variable name same as your class name, that's why you are getting the error. Change that to:

```
LikeButton *likeBtn = (LikeButton *)[sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:3];
```

Why are you dequeueing cells in `viewForHeaderInSection:` are you implemented `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method ?

Comment: Yes I'm implementing that later down in the code, thank you so much for helping me on my error.

Comment: We used to abbreviate button to btn back when we were limited to six character names.

Comment: @Zaph: I named it because when typing `likeButton`, there is a chance of autocompletion should popup the class name `LikeButton`